# Trying to extract password from auto generated email. But it is failing in various combinations

Tags: java

I am trying to extract password from email but unable to do so. The mail when extracted for password will have html chars. when the mail utility is returning the content of email
It should work for all following combinations of passwords

```
String s = "Y5y&gt;eAy&amp;";
String s2 = "jO3S&gt;Eu1</p>";
String s4 = "jO3SEu1!";
String s5 = "u8P&gt;SIzk";
String s6 = "83Pp>epn";
String s7 = "83Pp&gt;epn";

String s3 = "<p>A temporary password has been created for your user account.</p>" +
                "<p>User Name:  abc+1676532236813@abc.com</p>" +
                "<p>Password: 83Pp&gt;epn</p>" +
                "<p>Log into the platform with the provided URL to complete your user account set up.</p>\n" +
                "<p><a href=\"https://example.com/login\">https://login-dev.example.com/login</a></p>";
```

I have tried following code but it is not working

```
int index = s3.indexOf("Password: ");
        String password = "";
//        System.out.println("first is "+password);
        password = s3.substring(index + 11, index + 24);
        System.out.println("index of / is " + password.indexOf("/"));


        if (password.indexOf("/") == 12) {
            password = s3.substring(index + 11, index + 22);
            password = password.replaceAll("(.*?)|(&.*?;)|([ ]{2,})", "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("hello");
            password = s3.substring(index + 11, index + 19);
            password = password.replaceAll("(.*?)|(&.*?;)|([ ]{2,})", "");
        }
        password = password.replace("&gt;", "");
        System.out.println(password);
```

Can anyone help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String password = s3.substring(s3.indexOf("<p>Password: ") + 13);
password = password.substring(0, password.indexOf("</p>"));
System.out.println(password);
```

The code searches for the String `<p>Password:` , removes everything infront of it and afterwards remove all and including after `</p>`.

I don´t know if I understood your question correct, but if you want to unescape HTML characters afterwards, you could use the StringEscapeUtils class:

```
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(password);
System.out.println(withCharacters);
```

Simply add it before the System.out.

Of course, with this the solution, the String before the password has to always be the same.

Comment: Sorry got busy with other tasks so didn't get chance to test your code. In the email that I will be receiving will have &gt; and &amp; I will be replacing them with ">" and "&amp;" with "&"    password = password.replace("&gt;",">").trim();
        password = password.replace("&amp;","&").trim();.  However sometimes even "&" may come alone. How do I check if "&" is without "&amp;" and "&gt;" so that I can take as it is

Comment: I think you can use this method:
String withCharacters = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(password);